# Jquery .addClass to parent-parent var with .each

Tags: jquery

Please take a look at the code below:

```
var firstcalenderd = $('div.pmu-instance:eq(0) div.pmu-days div.pmu-button:not(.pmu-not-in-month)').each(function() {
   var parsingevents = $('.rko-calendar-event');

   parsingevents.each(function() {   
      if(firstcalenderm == gmonth && currday == gday)
      {
         .addClass('eventday');
      }  
   });
});
```

As you can see, there are two `.each()` loops , one in another one. If conditions are met in second one (child of first), I want to add class to the first one. 
How could I call this parent var?

`firstcalenderd.addClass('eventday')` - is not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to cache it in a variable,

```
var firstcalenderd = $('div.pmu-instance:eq(0) div.pmu-days div.pmu-button:not(.pmu-not-in-month)').each(function() {
   var parsingevents = $('.rko-calendar-event');
   var parentVar = $(this);

   parsingevents.each(function() {   
      if(firstcalenderm == gmonth && currday == gday)
      {
          parentVar.addClass('eventday');
      }  
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, everything is working. I will accept your answer after time limit will go off.